# Issuse with json/nodejs, sets [object, Object] instead of values

Tags: json, node.js, python-requests

so I got a small API that listens for HTTP POST and sets some values to the body of the POST.
But I can't for the life of me figure out why this becomes [object Object] instead of the values I set.

Packages used:
request,
Commander,
colors

Here's a gist of the problematic code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/49ff43ab661bef7705f8c6f088dbc256

Comment: Cannot see your input or output values. Please explain more.

Comment: Bottom server, top the script.
https://i.imgur.com/BAozo1s.png

Answer (score -1):

Pass JSON.stringify(yourobject) to colors instead of the object :

```
 console.log(colors.yellow(JSON.stringify(infoOptions.body)));
```

instead of

```
 console.log(colors.yellow(infoOptions.body));
```

Otherwise colors call the .toString() method of the object which is : "[object Object]"

Comment: Did that, well It solved the issue with the console output being [object Object], but the render still shows [object Object].

Here's the render output https://i.imgur.com/McVp0V6.png

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/727cac3464647974a33762052a9b1ed5 For server side and the render (Also added the rest of the code)

Comment: Probably because you have an object inside it... Do a console.log(JSON.stringify(info)) before rendering the view to see what there's inside

Comment: Solved it, I had to change in server.js:48 to info.message/date/color to req.body.message.message/date/color!